# What is the difference between Linq to XML Descendants and Elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have came across both these keywords in the VS IntelliSense. I tried to googling the difference between them and did not get a clear answer. Which one of these have the best performance with small to medium XML files. Thanks

Answer (score 321, accepted):

[`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) finds only those elements that are **direct** descendents, i.e. immediate children.

[`Descendants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) finds children at any level, i.e. children, grand-children, etc...

---

Here is an example demonstrating the difference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<foo>
    <bar>Test 1</bar>
    <baz>
        <bar>Test 2</bar>
    </baz>
    <bar>Test 3</bar>
</foo>
```

Code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
XElement root = doc.Root;

foreach (XElement e in root.Elements("bar"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Elements : " + e.Value);
}

foreach (XElement e in root.Descendants("bar"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Descendants : " + e.Value);
}
```

Result:

```
Elements : Test 1
Elements : Test 3
Descendants : Test 1
Descendants : Test 2
Descendants : Test 3
```

If you know that the elements you want are immediate children then you will get better performance if you use `Elements` instead of `Descendants`.

Comment: Great answer, I always thought the two were a little backwards as highlighted in your description (when describing Elements, you always need to use the word "descendant" where as it is a bit more optional when talking about Descendants

Answer (score 24):

`Descendants` will search the entire subtree of the current element for the specified name (or will return a flattened version of the tree if no name is provided), whereas `Elements` searches only the immediate children of the current element.