# Finding xsd element using attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

How can i find complexType element knowing it's name(station)?
I'm beginner
Here is an entire xsd code:
http://pastebin.com/ymuPDCCb
This doesn't work.

```
private XElement GetComplexType(string typeName)
{
    XElement complexType = xsdSchema.Elements("complexType")
        .Where(a => a.Attributes("name").FirstOrDefault() != null && a.Attribute("name").Value==typeName)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return complexType;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the `xs` namespace and you need to query all levels using `Descendants()` instead of `Elements()`, like so:

```
private static void ParseXml()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\schema.xml");

    if (doc != null)
    {
        XElement nodes = GetComplexType("station", doc);

        if (nodes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("station found...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("station NOT found!!");
        }
    }
}

private static XElement GetComplexType(string typeName, XDocument xsdSchema)
{
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
    XElement complexType = xsdSchema.Descendants(ns + "complexType")
        .Where(a => a.Attributes("name").FirstOrDefault() != null && a.Attribute("name").Value == typeName)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return complexType;
}
```

Check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705020/what-is-the-difference-between-linq-to-xml-descendants-and-elements) answer for more info on Elements vs Descendants

Comment: it still returns null, so   there must be some other problems

Comment: still doesn't resolve my problem of finding nodes by its attribute value

Comment: Can you post the complete XSD?

Comment: there you go, i posted complete xsd

Comment: thx. How are you instantiating the 'xsdSchema' object? I have no problem retrieving the complexType node from the schema XML using the code above...

Comment: XDocument xsdSchema;
 xsdSchema = XDocument.Load(filePath);   (and typeName=="station")

Comment: I've put my complete sample in the answer. The code above successfully finds a 'complexType' node with name 'station' on my side...