# Xml node not actually node, need to get attribute

Tags: c#, xml

Here is the xml:

```
<_text_column min_width="0" max_width="2031051">
    <PF_Para_Base align="center">
        <_char data_tag="PricesGoodText" font_size="35270" bold="true" italic="false" font_name="/ITC Franklin Gothic Demi" text_color="White">PricesGoodText</_char>
    </PF_Para_Base>
</_text_column>
```

I am opening and appending a root to the file because I was getting a multiple root error with the file

```
using (var fs = new StreamReader(fullFileName))
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(fs, settings))
{
    while (xr.Read())
    {
        if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            rootElement.Add(XElement.Load(xr.ReadSubtree()));
        }
    }
}

var attr = rootElement.Elements("char").Attribute("data_tag");
```

I need to get the attribute `data_tag` out of the node `_char`. It comes back as `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rootElement.Elements("_char").Attributes("data_tag");` is wrong as `Elements` read just the direct children, you should use `Descendants`:

```
rootElement.Descendants("_char").Select(c => c.Attribute("data_tag").Value);
```

Check this SO question: [What is the difference between Linq to XML Descendants and Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705020/what-is-the-difference-between-linq-to-xml-descendants-and-elements)

Comment: ugh... simple solutions are the worst to spot