# Remove specific node from xml

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my xml

```
 <result>
  <client></client>
  <message></message>
  <record>
     <message></message>
   </record>
</result>
```

I want to remove the "message" node which is right below "result"
when I tried to remove it by using below code:

```
 responseXml.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == "client" || e.Name == "message").Remove();
```

It is removing "message" which is under "record" but I don't want this.
I want to remove only "message" under "result"

Expected xml:

```
 <result>
  <client></client>
  <record>
     <message></message>
   </record>
</result>
```

Please suggest me here.

Comment: Why is `<client></client>` still in your expected xml?

Comment: Consider checking out behavior of methods you are using - sometimes you may find answer yourself. For this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705020/what-is-the-difference-between-linq-to-xml-descendants-and-elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Descendants()` will return all elements (children and grand-children etc.), while `Elements()` will only return immediate children.

```
responseXml.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name == "message").Remove();
```

You could probably use the shorter `.Element("message")` syntax, but be aware that this method only returns the first element found. If you have more than one `<message>` it wont return/remove them all.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    string xml =@"
 <result>
  <client></client>
  <message></message>
  <record>
     <message></message>
   </record>
</result>";

XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);    
root.Element("message").Remove();    
}
```

Removes exact element "message" directly under root node.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Its working fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Element(name)`, which returns a single `XElement` (calling `Elements` or `Descendants` returns a `IEnumerable<XElement>`):

```
responseXml.Root.Element("message").Remove();
```