# How I can get an array of array using Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

How I can get a list of all genres?
Now I only get the first genre of each song.

**XML file:**

```
<Library xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Songs>
    <Song>
      <Title>High Hopes</Title>
      <Genres>
        <Genre>Rock</Genre>
        <Genre>American</Genre>      
      </Genres>
     </Song>
    <Song>
      <Title>Imagine</Title>
      <Genres>
        <Genre>Pop</Genre>
        <Genre>Unplugged</Genre>      
      </Genres>
    </Song>
  </Songs>
</Library>
```

**C# code:**

```
public void ListGenres()
{
  System.Xml.Linq.XElement xLibrary = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(@"c:\Library.xml");
  System.Xml.Linq.XElement xSongs = xLibrary.Element("Songs");
  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> genres = 
                from code in xSongs.Elements("Song")
                let genre = (string)code.Element("Genres").Element("Genre")
                orderby genre
                select genre;
  foreach (string genre in genres)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(genre);
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Pop
Rock
```

**But I need:**

```
Rock
American
Pop
Unplugged
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not performing any filters, you can directly use `Descendants` like this:-

```
XDocument xLibrary = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Library.xml");
IEnumerable<string> result = xLibrary.Descendants("Genre").Select(x => (string)x);
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:-

```
IEnumerable<string> res = from genre in xdoc.Descendants("Genre")
                                      select (string)genre;
```

You need to import `using System.Linq;` for this.This will produce the outpu you expect i.e. **Rock American Pop Unplugged** even though it is not ordered. You can always use `order by` caluse for that.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705042/1529657) answer to understand why I am using `Descendants` instead of `Elements`.

Comment: IEnumerable<string> result = xLibrary.Descendants("Genre").Select(x => (string)x).Distinct();

Comment: @RahulSingh Nice Explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any additional filtering of genres, you can easily get all the genres in document like this:

```
var genres = xLibrary.XPathSelectElements("//Genre").Select(g => g.Value);
```

Note: `XPathSelectElements` is an extension method, make sure you're using `System.Xml.XPath` namespace in your sourcecode in order to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

In case your xml also contains "Genre" nodes for elements other than songs:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var genres = doc.Root.Element("Songs")
                     .Elements("Song")
                     .Elements("Genres")
                     .Elements("Genre")
                     .Select(e => e.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are selecting a single genre using `.Element(string)`, you should use `.GetElements(string)` if you dont wanna use `.Descendants(string)`:

```
IEnumerable<string> genres = xSongs
    .Elements("Song")
    .SelectMany(song => song
        .Element("Genres")
        .Elements("Genre")
        .Select(genre => genre.Value));
```

The linq above is equivalent to `"xSongs.(many)Song.Genres.(many)Genre.Value"`

And if you rather use query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<string> genres = from song in xSongs.Elements("Song")
                             let songGenres = song.Element("Genres").Elements("Genre")
                             from genre in songGenres
                             select genre.Value;
```

Since you have more than one *one-to-many* relation in your xml, you need to have more than one `from` in your linq query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need ordered list of genre for each song. You can try below code.

```
public void ListGenres()
{
  System.Xml.Linq.XElement xLibrary = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(@"c:\Library.xml");
  System.Xml.Linq.XElement xSongs = xLibrary.Element("Songs");
  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<List<string>> genresList = 
                from code in xSongs.Elements("Song")
                let genreList = (string)code.Element("Genres")
                select genreList.ToList();
  foreach (List<string> genreList in genresList)
  {
     var orderedList = genreList.OrderBy(x=>x);
     foreach(string genre in orderedList)
      Console.WriteLine(genre);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<Library xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                  "<Songs>" +
                    "<Song>" +
                      "<Title>High Hopes</Title>" +
                      "<Genres>" +
                        "<Genre>Rock</Genre>" +
                        "<Genre>American</Genre>" +
                      "</Genres>" +
                     "</Song>" +
                    "<Song>" +
                      "<Title>Imagine</Title>" +
                      "<Genres>" +
                        "<Genre>Pop</Genre>" +
                        "<Genre>Unplugged</Genre>" +
                      "</Genres>" +
                    "</Song>" +
                  "</Songs>" +
                "</Library>";

            XElement library = XElement.Parse(input);

            var results = library.Descendants("Song").Select(x => new
            {
                title = x.Element("Title").Value,
                genres = x.Descendants("Genre").Select(y => new {
                    genere = y.Value
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<string> genres = xSongs.Elements("Song")
    .Select(song => song.Element("Genres"))
    .SelectMany(genres => genres.Elements("Genre"))
    .Select(genre => genre.Value)
    .OrderBy(x => x);
```