# Get attribute value of parent node by Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a problem parsing a XML file using Linq to XML.

My XML structure looks like:

```
<Module>
  <Variable Name="Variable1" Value="True" />
  <Variable Name="Variable2" Value="True" />
  <Variable Name="Variable3" Value="True" />
  </Task>
  <Task Name="Task1">
    <Variable Name="Task1Variable1" Value ="True" />
    <Variable Name=" Task1Variable2" Value ="True" />
  </Task>
  <Task Name="Task2">
    <Variable Name="Task2Variable1" Value ="True" />
    <Variable Name=" Task2Variable2" Value ="True" />
  </Task>
</Module>
```

What I intend to do is to get the value of each Variable Name attribute.
So for the elements that are directly under the node Module it works fine with

```
var variables = (from cfg in _xElements.Descendants("Module").Elements("Variable")
                                       select cfg.Attribute("Name"));
```

The problem starts with the Variable Name attributes that are under the Task nodes because I also need the information about the Task Name.

So what I would like to get is the information about the Variable name plus the information about the Task Name that is the parent node of the variable element.

Is there a way to get this done with Linq?

Comment: _xElements.Descendants("Variable")???

Comment: @Viru: Whats your point?

Comment: @Viru: THX, my problem was that i didnt know that i can use "select new" in this way. I always thought that i must instantiate a new object of any type. Thx a lot.

Comment: @ck8vi yeah, this is called anonymous type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parent property of XElement

```
var variables = (from cfg in _xElements.Descendants("Variable")
                                       select new
{
  TaskName = cfg.Parent.Name == "Task"? cfg.Parent.Attribute("Name"):null,   
  VariableAttribute = cfg.Attribute("Name")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is since you are using [Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765(v=vs.110).aspx) it is returning only the `Variable` which are direct child of root node. Use [Descedants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) instead.

This query will give you the expected output:-

```
 var variables = (from cfg in _xElements.Descendants("Variable")
                  select cfg.Attribute("Name"));
```

[Check difference between Elements and Descendants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705042/1529657).

Answer (score 0):

Descendants won't work in this case.  Try complete solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<Module>" +
                  "<Variable Name=\"Variable1\" Value=\"True\" />" +
                  "<Variable Name=\"Variable2\" Value=\"True\" />" +
                  "<Variable Name=\"Variable3\" Value=\"True\" />" +
                  "<Task Name=\"Task1\">" +
                    "<Variable Name=\"Task1Variable1\" Value =\"True\" />" +
                    "<Variable Name=\"Task1Variable2\" Value =\"True\" />" +
                  "</Task>" +
                  "<Task Name=\"Task2\">" +
                    "<Variable Name=\"Task2Variable1\" Value =\"True\" />" +
                    "<Variable Name=\"Task2Variable2\" Value =\"True\" />" +
                  "</Task>" +
                "</Module>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc.Elements("Module").Select(m => new {
                variables = m.Elements("Variable").Select(n => new {
                   name = (string)n.Attribute("Name"),
                   value = (string)n.Attribute("Value")
                }).ToList(),
                tasks = m.Elements("Task").Select(o => new {
                    name = (string)o.Attribute("Name"),
                    variables = o.Elements("Variable").Select(p => new {
                        name = (string)p.Attribute("Name"),
                        value = (string)p.Attribute("Value")
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```