# XElement.Elements() returning empty collection

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get the values from an XElement that I'm receiving from db notification.
The xml structure is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <inserted>
        <row>
            <CODI_AVERIA>22</CODI_AVERIA>
            <NUMERO_LINIA>2</NUMERO_LINIA>
            <DIA>2016-07-17T00:00:00</DIA>
            <HORA>1899-12-30T10:26:15.790</HORA>
            <CODI_USUARI>1</CODI_USUARI>
            <ACCIO>0</ACCIO>
            <CODI_PSEUDO>-1</CODI_PSEUDO>
        </row>
    </inserted>
</root>
```

And this is the method that I'm using to get the data, and it returns me a List that is empty.

```
static void getAccio(XElement xml)
{
    try
    {
        xml.Descendants("deleted").Remove();

        var items = xml.Elements("row").Select(n => new
        {
            Codi_averia = n.Element("CODI_AVERIA").Value,
            Numero_linia = n.Element("NUMERO_LINIA)").Value,
            Accio = n.Element("ACCIO").Value
        }).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I have tried to get the value of each field apart and it doesn't allow me to get them separetly as XElements.

Comment: Does your XML have a namespace?

Comment: is `<inserted>` the [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) of your XML file or is it contained in some larger element?

Comment: @dbc it has  '<root>' element just at the begining and at the end of the xml that I copy... it's my fault

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you [edit] your question to create a [mcve] showing the root element and to show how you get the `XElement xml` variable.  Probably the answer of @GiladGreen is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.Descendants()` instead of `.Elements()`:

```
var items = xml.Descendants("row").Select(n => new
    {
        Codi_averia = n.Element("CODI_AVERIA").Value,
        Numero_linia = n.Element("NUMERO_LINIA)").Value,
        Accio = n.Element("ACCIO").Value
    }).ToList();
```

*`.Elements` finds only those elements that are direct descendents, i.e. immediate children*. - And I assume that your `XElement` is the parent of the `inserted` section.

For difference between `.Element` and `.Descendants` [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705020/what-is-the-difference-between-linq-to-xml-descendants-and-elements)

If you don't want to find them in all inner elements too then do `.Element("inserted").Elements("rows")`

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your document doesn't have any root element with the name `row`. Instead, you need to select `inserted` first, and enumerate the `row` elements of `inserted`:

```
var xml = @"<inserted>  
    <row>    
        <CODI_AVERIA>21</CODI_AVERIA>    
        <NUMERO_LINIA>2</NUMERO_LINIA>    
        <DIA>2016-07-17T00:00:00</DIA>    
        <HORA>1899-12-30T10:26:15.790</HORA>    
        <CODI_USUARI>1</CODI_USUARI>    
        <ACCIO>0</ACCIO>    
        <CODI_PSEUDO>-1</CODI_PSEUDO>  
    </row>
</inserted>";

var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var items = xdoc.Element("inserted").Elements("row").Select(n => new
{
    Codi_averia = n.Element("CODI_AVERIA").Value,
    Numero_linia = n.Element("NUMERO_LINIA").Value,
    Accio = n.Element("ACCIO").Value

}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code `("NUMERO_LINIA)")` is wrong because of additionnal quote and parenthesis.

This works for me :

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

var lst = (from n in xd.Descendants("row")
           select new
           {
                 Codi_averia = n.Element("CODI_AVERIA").Value,
                 Numero_linia = n.Element("NUMERO_LINIA").Value,
                 Accio = n.Element("ACCIO").Value
           }).ToList();

foreach (var item in lst)
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", item.Codi_averia, item.Numero_linia, item.Accio));
```