# How do I get the value of an attribute using linq to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
    <result>
        <rowset name="typeids" key="typeID" columns="typeName,TypeID">
            <row typeName="Construction Blocks" typeID="3828" />
        </rowset>
    </result>
</eveapi>
```

Currently I am trying to get the value of the `typeID` attribute from this xml using this code:

```
var result = from el in doc.Elements("row")
             where (string)el.Attribute("typeName") == "Construction Blocks"
             select el.Attribute("typeID").Value;

foreach (string el in result)
{
    typeID.Add(Convert.ToInt32(el));
}
```

However the `foreach` statement never fires. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Sorry, I put in the wrong xml. Correct xml is now there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use `.Descendants()` and not `Elements`:

```
var result = (from el in doc.Descendants("row")
              where (string)el.Attribute("typeName") == "Construction Blocks"
              select Convert.ToInt32(el.Attribute("typeID").Value)).ToList();

// See that you can just perform the `Convert` in the `select` instead of having a 
// `foreach`. If you need to put the results into an initialized list then you can remove 
// the `ToList()` and just have an `AddRange` on your list to the `result`
```

- To understand the difference refer to: [What is the difference
  between Linq to XML Descendants and Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3705020/6400526)

Answer (score 0):

In your xml, there is no **`typeName`** named **`Construction Blocks`** , so the result will be obviously null.

So foreach loop does not have any collection.