# Replace part of large XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have large XML file, and I need to replace elements with some name (and all inner elements) with another element. For example - if this element `e`:

```
<a>
<b></b>
<e>
   <b></b>
   <c></c>
</e>
</a>
```

After replace `e` for `elem`:

```
<a>
<b></b>
<elem></elem>
</a>
```

update: I try use `XDocument` but xml size more then 2gb and I have `SystemOutOfMemoryException`

update2: my code, but xml not transform

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("xml_file.xml");
XmlWriter wr = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out);
while (reader.Read())
   {
       if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "e")
       {
           wr.WriteElementString("elem", "val1");
           reader.ReadSubtree();
       }
            wr.WriteNode(reader, false);
   }
wr.Close();
```

update 3:

```
<a>
<b></b>
<e>
   <b></b>
   <c></c>
</e>
<i>
  <e>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
  </e>
</i> 
</a>
```

Comment: One easy way I can think of is to just parse the xml and when you find an element that you want to replace then just remove it from it's parent's ChildNodes and add the new empty element in it's place.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: You might want to expand on the issue. On the face value what you asking is trivial, so any additional information as to what you problem is could help. Did you get any error messages? What does your code look like? (If you don't have any code yet you should start by writing it, and *then* when it does not work show it and ask for help here)

Comment: You'll need to do something like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mfussell/archive/2005/02/12/371546.aspx), you can basically just stream the contents of the `XmlReader` straight to the `XmlWriter` similarly to your example code, but handling all node types. Using `WriteNode`, as in your example code, will add the node *and all child nodes*, so you wouldn't be able to handle each descendant in your source XML.

In addition, you need to make sure you read to the end of the element you want to skip - `ReadSubtree` creates an `XmlReader` for this, but it doesn't actually do any reading.  You need to ensure this is read to the end.

The resulting code might look like this:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), rs))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, ws))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                var subTreeReader = reader.ReadSubtree();
                if (HandleElement(reader, writer))
                {
                    ReadToEnd(subTreeReader);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                    writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                    if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                    {
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
            case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                writer.WriteWhitespace(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                writer.WriteCData(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                writer.WriteEntityRef(reader.Name);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                writer.WriteDocType(reader.Name, reader.GetAttribute("PUBLIC"), reader.GetAttribute("SYSTEM"), reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                break;
        }
    }    
}

private static void ReadToEnd(XmlReader reader)
{
    while (!reader.EOF)
    {
        reader.Read();
    }
}
```

Obviously put whatever your logic is inside `HandleElement`, returning `true` if the element is handled (and therefore to be ignored). The implementation for the logic in your example code would be:

```
private static bool HandleElement(XmlReader reader, XmlWriter writer)
{
    if (reader.Name == "e")
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("element", "val1");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FFIBU4

Comment: but this not working for this situation - see update 3

Comment: @e1s Oops.  Should have done some more testing.  It seems `ReadOuterXml` isn't really a suitable replacement for reading the subtree reader through.  I've updated the answer & demo.

Answer (score 1):

try this (saw the C# tag :D) :

```
        XElement elem = new XElement("elem");
        IEnumerable<XElement> listElementsToBeReplaced = xDocument.Descendants("e");
        foreach (XElement replaceElement in listElementsToBeReplaced)
        {
            replaceElement.AddAfterSelf(elem);
        }
        listElementsToBeReplaced.Remove();
```

Comment: I cant use `xDocument` because size of xml more then 2Gb and I have `SystemOutOfMemoryException`. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

I would replace it with a regular expression, matching e elements with all its content and ending with the closing tag, and replacing it with the new elem element.
This way you can do it in any editor with search/replace that supports regular expressions and programatically in any language.

Comment: I think it maybe need balance group to `Regex.Replace`

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = @"<a>
<b></b>
<e>
<b></b>
<c></c>
</e>
</a>";
string patten = @"<e[^>]*>[\s\S]*?(((?'Open'<e[^>]*>)[\s\S]*?)+((?'-Open'</e>)[\s\S]*?)+)*(?(Open)(?!))</e>";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(xml,patten,"<ele></ele>"));
```

Use regex,also can use LinqToXml

Answer (score 0):

```
// example data:
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(
@"
<a>
<b></b>
<e>
   <b></b>
   <c></c>
</e>
<c />
<e>
   <b></b>
   <c></c>
   <c></c>
</e>
</a>
");
            // you can use xpath, then you need to add:
            // using System.Xml.XPath;
            List<XElement> elementsToReplace = xmldoc.XPathSelectElements("a/e").ToList();

            // or pure linq-to-sql:
            // elementsToReplace = xmldoc.Elements("a").Elements("e").ToList();

            foreach (XElement elem in elementsToReplace)
            {
                // setting Value of XElement to an empty string causes the resulting xml to look like this:
                // <elem></elem>
                // and not like this:
                // <elem />
                elem.ReplaceWith(new XElement("elem", ""));
                // if you don't mind self closing tags, then:
                // elem.ReplaceWith(new XElement("elem"));
            }
```

I didn't measure the performance but [rumour has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629596/xpathselectelement-vs-descendants) the difference is not very significant.

XPath syntax, if you need it: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: @e1s you can manually set stack size of your worker thread to more than 2gb:  Thread thread = new Thread(myDoWorkMethod, stackSize); If the memory is going to be the problem anyway, I think you should consider using the reader/writer approach that Charles Mager proposed in the comment to your question