# Editing an object that is saved as a binary file

Tags: c#, serialization

I have created a serialization object (for example student) in C# and I saved it as a binary file in this way:

```
public static void WriteToBinaryFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, 
bool append = false)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, append ? FileMode.Append : 
    FileMode.Create))
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new 
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
    }
}
```

So now I want to change the name of the student and save the edited student object, but I do not want to delete the previous file and replace the new edited file instead of previous, but I just want to apply the changes in the original file.

It's like I want to change the name of a person, but not by killing him! and creating a person similar to the original person but with a new name.

Comment: You cant do that.  Serialized data is only useful to recreate the object(s) the data represents.  To make a change - deserialize, change, serialize again.  Also, what the heck does python have to do with this??? Use only *relevant* tags

Comment: I already told you: deserialize the data saved to  new object or List<T>, make the change(s) and serialize it again.  When you researched the BinaryFormatter, did you not give any thought to how you would read it back or make these changes?

Comment: The code posted here already saves your object.  If you make changes, then it sounds like you have a collection of these things.  Rather than saving one by one, store them in a `List<T>` and you can save/serialize all of them all at once to the same file.  Naturally when you Deserialize, it will create a new List<T> with those same objects in it.

Comment: i learned how to read it back . but i did not found something about make changes

Comment: The comment you deleted said you wanted to *make a new one just like the saved one but with a different name*.  Making a new one means making a new one.  If you change the name of the saved one, you wont have 2.  You likely need a *collection* of them.  IF you truly just want to make changes, you just change the properties on `objectToWrite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit a binary serialized object. You have to deserialize it in order to edit anything.

Let me suggest an alternative approach. If you're only after saving the student data in a file so you could load and use it later, you could change the serialization method from binary to XML ([Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)) The XML format would allow you to find and edit a specific field in the file as it would be saved in a plain "as-is" form. Then you could edit it without the need for loading everything into memory and and eventually overwriting the original file ([Replace part of large XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405980/replace-part-of-large-xml-file)) This blog post has a concrete example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mfussell/2005/02/12/combining-the-xmlreader-and-xmlwriter-classes-for-simple-streaming-transformations/

Comment: I saw the code on the link you introduced(), but there was no "path" to store xml file in those codes . in binaryformatter  i gave a path to system to save the binary file .but in Xml Serialization i did not see any path for storing files. i want to store my xml file  in @"d:\Students"  (for example) .